# Proving that a multivariable function is a bijection

Tags: number-theory, functions

I'm trying to prove that the function $f: \mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{N} \rightarrow \mathbb{N}$ defined by $f(m,n)=2^{m-1}(2n-1)$ is bijective, and thus demonstrate that $\mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{N}$ is countably infinite.

I tried to find an inverse directly, but that seemed to be the wrong method. I was also thinking of using the Fundamental Theorem of Arithmetic to factor any $n \in \mathbb{N}$, but wasn't sure how to do this rigorously. Any nudges would be appreciated.

Comment: f(0;n) and f(m;0) is not in N

Comment: @Hassan Zero is not an element of the natural numbers for this problem (and in my textbook in general).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For any odd number you can use $f(1,n)$ it is trivial to solve $g(n) = 2n - 1$.
For any even number it will have a factor $2^p$ so factor that off.  Set $m = p-1$ and solve for $n$ for the odd factors.

Comment: Do you mean $f(1,n)$?

Comment: Yes I did.  Thank you for the correction